# JavaFX TimeLine inside a for loop is skipping KeyFrames

Tags: java, javafx, timeline

I am building a Simon Says game in JavaFX. I have gotten most of it working, my only issue now is when you run the game it runs a for loop to generate the colours depending on which level you are on.

It seems to display one colour from the loop but it doesn't wait for the KeyFrame to finish before it flies through the rest of the loop and stores the values. How can I make the loop wait for the KeyFrame to complete so it displays all of the colour changes?

```
package assign3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javafx.animation.FillTransition;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Question2 extends Application
{

    public static final int RED = 1;
    public static final int GREEN = 2;
    public static final int BLUE = 3;
    public static final int ORANGE = 4;
    private int thisGameScore = 0;
    private int level = 1;
    private BorderPane obBorder;
    private HBox obPane;
    private HBox obStart;
    private Timeline tlRed;
    private Timeline tlBlue;
    private Timeline tlGreen;
    private Timeline tlOrange;
    private SequentialTransition stList = new SequentialTransition();
    private Button btStart;
    private ArrayList<Integer> colours;
    private ArrayList<Integer> guesses;

    @Override
    public void start( Stage obPrimeStage ) throws Exception
    {        
        boolean runGame = true;
        int guessIndex = 0;
        obBorder = new BorderPane();
        obPane = new HBox();
        obStart = new HBox();
        Button btRed = new Button("Red");
        Button btGreen = new Button("Green");
        Button btBlue = new Button("Blue");
        Button btOrange = new Button("Orange");
        btStart = new Button("Start");
        class RedTimeLine
        {
            Timeline tlRed;
            RedTimeLine()
            {
                tlRed = new Timeline();
                tlRed.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                        new KeyValue(obBorder.backgroundProperty(),
                                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)))));
                tlRed.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                        new KeyValue(obBorder.backgroundProperty(),
                                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)))));
            }

        }
        tlBlue = new Timeline();
        tlBlue.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                new KeyValue(obBorder.backgroundProperty(),
                        new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)))));
        tlBlue.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                new KeyValue(obBorder.backgroundProperty(),
                        new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)))));
        tlGreen = new Timeline();
        tlGreen.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                new KeyValue(obBorder.backgroundProperty(),
                        new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)))));
        tlGreen.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                new KeyValue(obBorder.backgroundProperty(),
                        new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)))));
        tlOrange = new Timeline();
        tlOrange.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                new KeyValue(obBorder.backgroundProperty(),
                        new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.ORANGE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)))));
        tlOrange.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                new KeyValue(obBorder.backgroundProperty(),
                        new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)))));


        obStart.getChildren().add(btStart);
        obPane.getChildren().addAll(btRed, btGreen, btBlue, btOrange);
        obBorder.setCenter(obPane);
        obBorder.setBottom(obStart);
        obPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        obStart.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene obScene = new Scene(obBorder, 400, 400);

        obPrimeStage.setTitle("Simon Says");
        obPrimeStage.setScene(obScene);
        obPrimeStage.show();



        btStart.setOnAction((ActionEvent start) -> {
            colours = new ArrayList<>();
            guesses = new ArrayList<>();
            obChange.handle(start);
            stList.play();
            System.out.println("Started new game");

        });  


        btRed.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> 
        {
            guesses.add(RED);
            if(guesses.get(guessIndex) != colours.get(guessIndex) )
            {
                obStart.getChildren().add(btStart);
                level = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(guesses.size() == colours.size())
                {
                    level += 1;
                    colours = new ArrayList<>();
                    guesses = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < level; i++)
                    {
                        obChange.handle(e);
                    }
                    stList.play();
                }
            }
        });

        btGreen.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> 
        {

            guesses.add(GREEN);
            if(guesses.get(guessIndex) != colours.get(guessIndex) )
            {
                obStart.getChildren().add(btStart);
                level = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(guesses.size() == colours.size())
                {
                    level += 1;
                    colours = new ArrayList<>();
                    guesses = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < level; i++)
                    {
                        obChange.handle(e);
                    }
                    stList.play();
                }
            }
        });

        btBlue.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> 
        {

            guesses.add(BLUE);
            if(guesses.get(guessIndex) != colours.get(guessIndex) )
            {
                obStart.getChildren().add(btStart);
                level = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(guesses.size() == colours.size())
                {
                    level += 1;
                    colours = new ArrayList<>();
                    guesses = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < level; i++)
                    {
                        obChange.handle(e);
                    }
                    stList.play();
                }
            }
        });

        btOrange.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> 
        {

            guesses.add(ORANGE);
            if(guesses.get(guessIndex) != colours.get(guessIndex) )
            {
                obStart.getChildren().add(btStart);
                level = 1;

            }
            else
            {
                if(guesses.size() == colours.size())
                {
                    level += 1;
                    guesses = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < level; i++)
                    {
                        obChange.handle(e);
                    }
                    stList.play();
                }
            }
        });

    }



    class ChangeColour implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
    {

        @Override
        public void handle( ActionEvent arg0 )
        {
            thisGameScore = 0;
            int randomColour = (int)((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

            if(randomColour == RED)
            {
                colours.add(RED);
                stList.getChildren().add(new RedTimeLine());

            }
            else if(randomColour == BLUE)
            {
                colours.add(BLUE);
                stList.getChildren().add(tlBlue);

            }
            else if(randomColour == GREEN)
            {
                colours.add(GREEN);
                stList.getChildren().add(tlGreen);

            }
            else if(randomColour == ORANGE)
            {
                colours.add(ORANGE);
                stList.getChildren().add(tlOrange);

            }
            obStart.getChildren().remove(btStart);


        }

    }

    ChangeColour obChange = new ChangeColour();




    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Application.launch(args);

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to post so much code to demonstrate this, you can create a [*minimal* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is still compilable and runnable and demonstrates only the issue at hand.  Doing so gives you a greater chance of getting great answers.

Comment: Aside: once you get this working, I advise you post the entire program as you originally have it in this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com and let the guys there pick it apart and give you advice on how to apply better code standards to improve the code quality.  My guess is that you would learn a lot from that.

Comment: @jewelsea I took your advice and cut out all of the excess code that was not required for the question. I'm not too worried about coding standards at this point, I will tidy it up once I understand the logic behind the syntax. Once I have everything working I have a coding standard I must fix it to abide by.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: A minimal example doesn't mean something that doesn't compile, please post minimal code that compiles with a copy and paste.  Maybe coding standard was the wrong wording, I meant using stuff like [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) such as a parameterized method for the button event handler rather than copy and pasting code four times for the btOrange, btBlue, etc handlers.

Comment: Well.. Seeing as I am still an amateur coder and this is the best I can do so far I will set it back to my code that compiles.

Comment: If someone can answer my question and I get it working I will update with a more concise solution.

Comment: If you do that, please place the working more concise solution in a [self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would do something like this:

```
public void playSequence(int sequenceLength, double speed) {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

    for (int i = 0; i < sequenceLength; i++) {
        Color color = colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)];
        Segment segment = segmentMap.get(color);

        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(i), new KeyValue(segment.litProperty(), true)
                ),
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(i + 0.9), new KeyValue(segment.litProperty(), false)
                )
        );

        isPlaying.set(true);
        timeline.setOnFinished(event -> isPlaying.set(false));
        timeline.setRate(speed);
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

The above example uses a Timeline, with the start time at which each segment is lit varying to light each segment in sequence.

*Full sample*

[image: simon]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.*;

public class SimpleSimon extends Application {
    private int sequenceLength = 1;
    private int speed = 1;

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Simon simon = new Simon();

        Button play = new Button("Play");
        play.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20px;");
        play.disableProperty().bind(simon.isPlayingProperty());
        play.setOnAction(event -> {
            simon.playSequence(sequenceLength, speed);
            sequenceLength++;
            speed *= 1.05;
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, simon, play);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Simon extends Group {
    private static final Random random = new Random(42);

    private final Color[] colors = {
            RED, GREEN, BLUE, ORANGE
    };

    private Map<Color, Segment> segmentMap = new HashMap<>();

    private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper isPlaying = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();

    public Simon() {
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            Segment segment = new Segment(colors[i], i * 90);
            getChildren().add(segment);
            segmentMap.put(colors[i], segment);
        }
    }

    public void playSequence(int sequenceLength, double speed) {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

        for (int i = 0; i < sequenceLength; i++) {
            Color color = colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)];
            Segment segment = segmentMap.get(color);

            timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                    new KeyFrame(
                            Duration.seconds(i), new KeyValue(segment.litProperty(), true)
                    ),
                    new KeyFrame(
                            Duration.seconds(i + 0.9), new KeyValue(segment.litProperty(), false)
                    )
            );
        }

        isPlaying.set(true);
        timeline.setOnFinished(event -> isPlaying.set(false));
        timeline.setRate(speed);
        timeline.play();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return isPlaying.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper isPlayingProperty() {
        return isPlaying;
    }
}

class Segment extends Arc {
    private BooleanProperty lit = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private static final double RADIUS = 100;

    private static final ColorAdjust litEffect = new ColorAdjust(0, 0, 0.5, 0);
    private static final ColorAdjust unlitEffect = new ColorAdjust(0, 0, 0, 0);

    public Segment(Color color, double angleOffset) {
        super(RADIUS, RADIUS, RADIUS, RADIUS,  angleOffset, 90);
        setFill(color);
        setType(ArcType.ROUND);

        setEffect(unlitEffect);
        lit.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                setEffect(lit.get() ? litEffect : unlitEffect)
        );
    }

    public void setLit(boolean lit) {
        this.lit.set(lit);
    }

    public boolean isLit() {
        return lit.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty litProperty() {
        return lit;
    }
}
```

A similar effect could be achieved via a [`SequentialTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html).

Comment: That makes sense. So I should build a list of which transitions to run, and then store each one in a SequentialTransition and run that?

Comment: So I used this explanation and it would likely work, except for the fact I need to store more than one instance of a specific colour animation. Now when I run I will get a duplicate child error.

Comment: Then make new instances, they won't be duplicates.

Comment: I updated my code to try and build an internal class for RedTimeline at the top of my JavaFX so I could build a new Timeline to add. The scope won't allow this to work, is there a way I can make it work?